# Python - Webscraping - Selecionar item no dropdown

Tags: python, web-scraping, selenium-webdriver

> Sou iniciante no Python e estou tendo algumas dificuldades com o
> webscraping no python.
>
> Estou tentando selecionar um item no dropdown e não estou conseguindo,
> ele para na parte do dropdown e não seleciona o item que eu quero que
> no caso é o "CBIO - Crédito de descarbonização" que fica dentro do
> primeiro dropdown. Podem me ajudar?? Muito obrigado.

##o código que não está funcionando##

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('http://estatisticas.cetip.com.br/astec/series_v05/paginas/lum_web_v05_series_introducao.asp?str_Modulo=Ativo&int_Idioma=1&int_Titulo=6&int_NivelBD=2/')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="divContainerIframeBmf"]/div/dl/dd[2]/a').click()
find_dp1 = \
driver.find_element(By.NAME,"ativo")
select_find_dp1 = Select(find_dp1)
select_find_dp1.select_by_visible_text("CBIO - Crédito de descarbonização")

time.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importando

```
import time 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select, WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = Options()
options.use_chromium = True
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument("disable-gpu")
```

Aqui você seleciona a pasta onde deseja salvar, coloquei somente um exemplo de pasta

```
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
  'download.default_directory': r'C:\Users\seu_usuario\sua_pasta\sua_subpasta'
})
```

Url base, baixando o driver do selenium e acessando a página

```
url = 'http://estatisticas.cetip.com.br/astec/series_v05/paginas/lum_web_v05_series_introducao.asp?str_Modulo=Ativo&int_Idioma=1&int_Titulo=6&int_NivelBD=2/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.get(url)
```

Aguardando o elemento estar disponível para o clique

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div[1]/div/div/div/dl/dd[2]/a'))).click()
```

O elemento que você deseja está dentro de um iframe por isso devemos utilizar o switch_to do selenium

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'dados_corpo'))
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'frameset').find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'frame')[0])
```

Transformamos o dropdown em um select e assim podemos utilizar o método  select_by_visible_text, que seleciona o valor com o texto que passamos como parametro

```
time.sleep(1)
ativos = Select(driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'ativo'))
ativos.select_by_visible_text('CBIO - Crédito de descarbonização')
```

Voltamos ao contexto padrão para acessar um iframe diferente e repetimos a operação anterior mas dessa vez com outro dropdown

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'dados_corpo'))
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'frameset').find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'frame')[1])

time.sleep(1)
informacoes = Select(driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'selectopcoes'))
informacoes.select_by_visible_text('Estoque')
```

Preenchemos os parâmetros da pesquisa

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'dados_corpo'))
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'frameset').find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'frame')[2])

time.sleep(1)
# Data Inicial 
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'DT_DIA_DE').send_keys('10')
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'DT_MES_DE').send_keys('10')
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'DT_ANO_DE').send_keys('2021')

# Data Final
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'DT_DIA_ATE').send_keys('01')
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'DT_MES_ATE').send_keys('02')
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'DT_ANO_ATE').send_keys('2022')
```

Enviamos o formulário

```
driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'button')[1].click()
```

Fazemos o download do arquivo

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'iframe'))
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'primary-text').find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'a').click()
```

Comment: Ótimo!

Porém, ele apareceu esse erro:

TypeError Traceback (última chamada mais recente) em 19 20 service = Service('C:\Program Files\Chrome Driver\chromedriver.exe') ---> 21 driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install ()), opções=opções) 22 driver.get(url) 23

TypeError: init () obteve um argumento de palavra-chave inesperado 'service'

Comment: @PedroRubbin, seu install() está com um espaço: install () e não deveria estar. Olhando também parece que você mudou alguma coisa, pois sua variável `options` virou `opções` e a mesma coisa ocorreu com o nome do parâmetro, o que não poderia acontecer.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Uma última dúvida, ele gerou a tabela no site que eu precisava depois de definir os itens nos dropdowns. 

Agora eu precisava que ele retornasse a tabela que ele gerou pra mim lá no site, pra que possa executar esse script no Power BI, pra que ele reconheça somente a parte da tabela que foi gerada por lá.

Se eu executá-lo assim, ele não vai reconhecer a tabela gerada no site.

OBS: já tenho os ambientes necessários e meu PowerBI já reconhece os scripts do Python normalmente

Comment: @PedroRubbin Retornar a tabela como? Fazer download?

Comment: o download eu consigo, mas como conseguiria fazer o download em formato para excel e direcioná-lo para uma pasta específica? no caso, uma pasta local

Comment: @PedroRubbin, adicionei como fazer o download para uma pasta selecionada por você. Caso tenha mais dúvidas sugiro abrir uma nova thread pois essa pergunta já abordou vários temas além da pergunta original. Caso tenha te ajudado e a resposta seja o que você precisava, considere em marcar como resposta correta. Grande Abraço!